# getline() как остановить чтение

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Использовал getline() для чтения строки с потока, после ее прочтения инструкция продолжает исполнятся и к новой не переходит. Можно ли как - то указать символ ( пр: '\n' ) на котором он закончит чтение. Пробовал с getdelim не помогло.

```
char *line = NULL;
int read = 0;
while (read != -1) {
  puts("enter a line");
  read = getline(&line, 0, stdin);
  printf("line = %s", line);
  printf("line length = %zu\n", read);
  puts("");
}
free(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо исправить ваше использование `getline`. Man читали? Кто вам разрешил передавать `0` в качестве второго аргумента?

Также: почему вы пытаетесь печатать значение типа `int` через формат `%zu`? (Хотя стоит заметить, что принимать результат `getline` следует в `ssize_t`, а не в `int`).

Вторым аргументом `getline` требует ненулевого указателя на объект типа `size_t`, содержащий размер выделенного буфера (на входе значение игнорируется, если указатель является нулевым, но на выходе в нем будет сохранено количество фактически выделенной памяти). А печать значений типа `int` делается через формат `%d`

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t mem_size = 0;

int read = 0;
while (read != -1) {
  puts("enter a line");
  read = getline(&line, &mem_size, stdin);
  printf("line = %s", line);
  printf("line length = %d\n", read);
  puts("");
}

free(line);
```

Все работает, как ожидалось.

Однако печатать содержимое строки после того, как `getline` вернуло `-1`, никакого смысла нет. Если `getline` удалось что-то успешно прочесть, то оно не вернет `-1` даже если чтение завершилось из-за натыкания на конец файла. Поэтому более осмысленной организацией такого цикла будет

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t mem_size = 0;

do {
  puts("enter a line");
  ssize_t read = getline(&line, &mem_size, stdin);
  if (read < 0)
    break;

  printf("line = %s", line);
  printf("line length = %zu\n", read);
  puts("");

} while (1);

free(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `getline` объявляется следующим образом.

```
ssize_t getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream):
```

Поэтому ваш код имеет неопределенное поведение, так как второй аргумент задан как `null` указатель.

```
read = getline(&line, 0, stdin);
                     ^^^
```

И в данном предложении неверно указана форматная строка

```
printf("line length = %zu\n", read);
                      ^^^^
```

так как переменная `read` в вашей программе имеет тип `int`, а не `size_t`, как оно должно быть.

Если функция `getline` вернула значение  `-1`, например, при наступлении события конца файла, то, тем не менее, содержимое буфера в вашей программе все равно выводится на консоль перед тем, как данное событие будет опознано в условии цикла `while`.

```
char *line = NULL;
int read = 0;
while (read != -1) {
  puts("enter a line");
  read = getline(&line, 0, stdin); // read уже равно -1, но буфер выводится на консоль
  printf("line = %s", line);
  printf("line length = %zu\n", read);
  //...
```

Чтобы прервать ввод строк, вы можете ввести комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+z в Windows, или Ctrl+d в Unix. можно также ввести соглашение, что если пользователь вводит пустую строку, просто нажав клавишу Enter, то это также считать признаком конца ввода.

Программа может, к примеру, выглядеть следующим образом

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( 1 ) 
    {
        size_t n;
        printf( "Enter a line (empty string - exit): ");

        if ( ( n = getline( &line, &size, stdin ) ) < 0 || *line == '\n' ) break;

         printf( "line = %s", line );
         printf( "line length = %zu\n", n );
         puts("");
    }

    free( line );

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может быть таким

```
Enter a line (empty string - exit): Hello daniil.vorobjew2017 
line = Hello daniil.vorobjew2017 
line length = 27

Enter a line (empty string - exit): Have a nice day
line = Have a nice day
line length = 16

Enter a line (empty string - exit):
```